# Automatically generate a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested

**UPDATE** This question has been marked as duplicate, which I contest. This covers the concept more generically and (I think) can be searched more easily. For example, the other question (and its lone answer as of the moment) does not mention "nested loop" anywhere, where "nested loop" is the generic term for this problem.

For example, I have the following lists:

```
level_0    level_1
foo        baz
bar        quux
           fizz
```

I want to make a tiled loop over all of them. In the convention below, `mem_0` is a member of `level_0`, and `mem_1` is a member of `level_1`.

```
for mem_0 in level_0:
    for mem_1 in level_1:
        print (mem_0, mem_1)
```

Effectively, I'll get the following:

```
(foo, baz)
(foo, quux)
(foo, fizz)
(bar, baz)
(bar, quux)
(bar, fizz)
```

My question now is, how do I automatically generate a nested loop? Say, I have 100 lists (i.e. I have up to `level_100`); I need to nest it down to 100 sub-levels.

Comment: `itertools.product(level_0, level_1)`. Or given a list of levels `itertools.product(*level_list)`. Note that if you have 100 lists, this will produce a HUGE number of combinations.

Comment: Related documentation link https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Having a list nested that deeply doesn't sound like a very good implementation. Are you sure lists are the ideal data structure?

Comment: Wow, that was quick, thank you! That should be an answer. At least it's a lazy iterator; memory might not be a problem until after some large number of lists I need to iterate over.

Comment: @IanAuld, I don't know. I guess I was exaggerating about the 100 lists? In my actual problem I only have 5 or 6 lists.

Comment: Looping over the result of `itertools.product` will produce an N-tuple, for N levels of nesting. So if you have 100 levels of nesting, your loop variable will be a 100-tuple, which you'll have to unpack, either programmatically by writing code that knows what comes from where in that 100-tuple, or by actually writing out the 100 different loop element symbols you want to use to refer to the 100 different tuple elements. Either way, it has a very bad code smell. Not to mention that even if each list had *only* two elements, you're talking about 2**100 different parameter combos :X

Comment: @Mr.F, good point. I forgot about that. What do you suggest might be better?

Comment: Well, first I would say you don't need to look at 2**100 parameter combos, whatever you are doing. Reduce the number of dimensions of the problem. Make an approximation that points you to which area of parameter space likely contains whatever you're looking for, then refine the parameter lists around that part of space and repeat. Something like a coarse grid search, or incremental search.

Comment: After that, I would try to re-frame the problem so that it was driven by a configuration script, maybe in a simple format like JSON, and had a little bit of loading to pull in the sets of params that are useful into some kind of data structure based on the actual processing to be applied.

Comment: If the length of the tuples could vary even in principle for different versions of this task, you should not use nested loops. `itertools.product` is the perfect tool for the job, use it and move on to what you were trying to do.